# Proof that $a(a+1)(2a+1)$ is divisible by $6$ for every integer a

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is from the book Elementary Number Theory by Jones & Jones

Example 3.6

Let us prove that a(a+1)(2a+1) is divisible by 6 for every integer a

By taking least absolute residues mod(6) we see that $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$.
If $a \equiv 0$ then $a(a+1)(2a+1) \equiv 0 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \equiv 0$, if $a \equiv 1$, then $a(a+1)(2a+1) \equiv 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6 \equiv 0$, and similar calculations (which you should try for yourself) show that $a(a+1)(2a+1) \equiv 0$ in the other 4 cases, so $6 \vert a(a+1)(2a+1)$ for all a.

---

I don't understand the proof at all starting with the first line - By taking least absolute residues mod(6) we see that $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$. - How does taking absolute residues mod(6) give $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$?

Comment: Well these residues are the six consecutive integers with least positive sum (not the way it is usually put). If you are looking for the residues with least absolute value - one representative from each class - it is ambiguous whether you take $3$ or $-3$ as representative of that class. Generally this gets resolved in favour of the positive value unless there is a special reason otherwise. (I've not seen it used, but you could choose the value which makes the product of the non-zero representatives positive, for example).

Comment: A quick (almost combinatorial) proof is the sum of the squares of the first $n$ positive integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remainder when you divide a number by $6$ can only be $0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Furthermore, $4 \equiv -2 \pmod{6}$ and $5 \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$.

After that, you just have to enumerate the $6$ cases to verify that it is true.

Comment: But how does taking absolute residues mod(6) give $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$?

Comment: These are the possible residues with the smallest magnitudes. It has to satisfy $-\frac{6}{2} < r \le \frac{6}{2}$

Comment: I am a beginner struggling with congruences for a month now. I really have no idea what you are on about.

Comment: The set of remainders can be written as $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. However, we can replace $4$ with $-2$ since $4-(-2) = 6$, similiarly we can replace $5$ by $-1$.

Comment: Got it - the part about the least absolute residues

Answer (score 1):

Induction:

- Check the validity for the base $a=1$.
  $$1(2)(3)$$ is divisible by 6. As it passes the first step, then we continues to the next step.
- Assume the claim is valid for $a=k$. Or we can express as
  $$k(k+1)(2k+1)=6m$$
- Check again for $a=k+1$.
  \begin{align}
     (k+1)(k+2)(2k+3) &= k(k+1)(2k+1) + 6(k+1)^2\\
                      &= 6m + 6 n\\
                      &= 6(m+n)
    \end{align}

  which is obviously divisible by 6.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand the proof at all starting with the first line - By taking least absolute residues mod(6) we see that $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$. - How does taking absolute residues mod(6) give $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$?
>
> > Let us prove that f(a) := a(a+1)(2a+1) is divisible by 6 for every integer a
> >
> > By taking least absolute residues mod(6) we see that $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2\ or\  
> >  3$.

Shifting the standard system of residues (remainders)  $\,0,1,\ldots 5\pmod{\!6}\,$ shows that any sequence $\,R\,$ of $\,6\,$ consecutive integers [forms a complete system of residues (or remainders)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242), i.e. every integer $\,a\,$ it is congruent to a unique $\,r_i\in R.\,$ Now $\!\bmod 6\!:\ a\equiv r_i\,\Rightarrow\, f(a)\equiv f(r_i)\,$ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Hence if we prove that $\,f(r_i)\equiv 0\,$ for all $\,r_i\in R\,$ then we can conclude that for *all* integers $a$ we have $\,f(a)\equiv 0,\,$  i.e $\,6\mid f(a).\,$  They prove $\,f(r_i)\equiv 0\,$ when $\,r_i = 1\,$ and leave to the reader the proofs for the remaining five elements of $R$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

It's much better to use:

$$a(a+1)(2a+1)=a(a+1)(2(a-1)+3)=2\underbrace{(a-1)a(a+1)}_{\text{ The product of } 3\text{ consecutive integers }}+3a(a+1)$$

Use [The product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n$ factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial)

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question - How does taking absolute residues mod(6) give $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 or 3$?

Comment: @user93353,  For any integer $2n,$  $$a\equiv 0,\pm1, \pm2, \cdots, n $$

Comment: Where did `2n` come into the picture from?

Comment: @user93353, Here $$2n=6$$

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. This is becoming like 20 questions

Comment: +1 neutralized. It is a good hint for other visitors. No need to down vote.