# Why the equivalence classes in the quotient set of $a=b\pmod m$ are named $\{0,1,...,m-1\}$ and there are $m$ and not $m+1$ equivalence classes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was reading about modular arithmetic. The congruencies modulo $m$ are equivalence relations. The textbook says that for the relation $a\equiv b\pmod m$ the quotient set of the equivalence classes are $Z/m={0,1,...,m-1}$ where each number represents the modulo $m$. So my question is: Why are there $m$ equivalence classes and why they end at $m-1$? If I have $a\equiv b\pmod 1$ then the equivalence classes are $$\begin{split}
R(0)&= [a \in \mathbb{Z}]\\ 
R(1)&=[a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{Z}: a=b-1]\\
\end{split}$$

---

which are two, not 1 .

Comment: You start counting at $0$.

Comment: Mod $1$ there is only ONE class since $1$ divides *every* integer.

Comment: I know that it starts counting at 0. But why it ends at m-1?

Comment: Because $m \equiv 0 \bmod m$ so you don't need a "new" class for $m$.  It's just the class of $0$ again.  Think of it this way:  if I divide by $3$ there are only $3$ possible remainders:  $0$, $1$, and $2$.  If you divide by $3$ and get remainder $3$ you did it wrong

Comment: You have the right idea looking at the trivial case of mod $1$. But you've made a mistake in thinking it has two equivalence classes. Every number is $0$ mod $1$, so every number is equivalent.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: The point is that $0,1,\ldots,m-1\,$ is a *complete residue system* $\bmod m,\,$ i.e. every integer $\,k\,$ is congruent to *exacly* one of them, as follows from the existence and uniqueness of the remainder in the division algorithm $\,k\div n.\ $ Said equivalently we can choose the *least nonnegative* element of $\,k+m\Bbb Z\,$ as a *normal form* (reduced) representative of each coset. These ideas are explained at length in the linked dupes.

Comment: They stop at $m-1$ because going further we have $\,m\equiv 0,\ m+1\equiv 1,\ldots$ so including these further elements would destroy uniqueness. But we could instead use $\,1,2,\ldots m\,$ (or any [consecutive sequence of $m$ integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242)). $\, n\equiv 0\pmod{\!1}\,$ by $\,1\mid (n-0)\,$ so $\,0\,$ is a complete residue system (special case of above).