# Prove $\frac{a(a^2+2)}{3}$ is an integer for all integer $a\geqslant 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

If $\frac{a(a^2+2)}{3}$ then $3\mid{a(a^2+2)}$.

By induction:

Lets define the set, $S=\left\{a\in N:a\geqslant1, 3\mid a(a^2+2) \right\}$

If $a=1$ then, $1\in S$

So we have to prove that if $k(k^2+2)=3m$ then $(k+1)((k+1)^2+2)=3n$ with $m,n\in Z$

If $k(k^2+2)=3m$ then,

$\begin{align*}k(k^2+2)+3(k^2+k+1)=&3m+3(k^2+k+1)\\=&3(m+k^2+k+1)\end{align*}$

Also,

$\begin{align*}k(k^2+2)+3(k^2+k+1)=&k^3+2k+3k^2+3k+3\\=&k^3+2k^2+k^2+2k+3k+3\\=&k^2(k+2)+k(k+2)+3(k+1)\\=&(k+2)(k^2+k)+3(k+1)\\ =&k(k+2)(k+1)+3(k+1)\\=&(k+1)(k(k+2)+3)\\ =&(k+1)(k^2+2k+1+2)\\ =&(k+1)((k+1)^2+2)\\ =&3(m+k^2+k+1) \end{align*}$

where $n=m+k^2+k+1$

Therefore,

$3\mid(k+1)((k+1)^2+2)$

Can I do it simplier using induction?

Comment: You haven't said what $S$ is. It's also quite hard to follow through. Perhaps include comments and numbering such as 'substituting ??? into (?), we get'.

Comment: What is meant by your first sentence?

Comment: You write $1\in S$. But what is $S$?

Comment: you can consider it mod 3. if a is 0,1,2 mod 3  what are the results ? if they all work then a can be any natural number and still work.

Comment: `Can I do it simplier using induction?` Not *a lot* simpler, but you can do it more easily *without* induction: 
$$
\frac{a(a^2+2\color{red}{+1-1})}{3} = \frac{3a}{3} + \frac{a(a^2-1)}{3}= a + \frac{(a-1)\,a\,(a+1)}{3}
$$
The numerator of the last fraction is the product of $\,3\,$ consecutive integers, so it is a multiple of $\,3\,$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can give a simpler and more conceptual *inductive* proof. Notice that

$\qquad\qquad  a(a^2+2)\, =\, a(a^2\!-\!1 + 3)\, =\, \color{#0a0}{(a-1)a(a+1)} + 3a$

so it suffices to show that one of any $\rm\color{#0a0}{3\ consecutive\ integers}$ is divisible by $3$

This has a simple inductive proof. Note that shifting such a sequence  by one simply replaces the old least element $\,\:\color{#C00}n\,$ by the new greatest element $\,\color{#C00}{n+3}$

$$ \begin{array}{}  \:\color{#C00}n &  n+1 &  n+2   \\
                    \to  &  n+1 &  n+2 &  \color{#C00}{n+3} \end{array}$$

Since $ \: \color{#C00}n\equiv \color{#C00}{n+3} \pmod{\! 3},\,$ the shift does not change the set of remainders $\bmod 3$  of the elements. Thus the remainders remain the same as in the base case $ \ 0,1,2\: =\: $ *all* possible remainders mod $ \,3.\,$ Therefore the sequence has an element with remainder $\,0,\,$ i.e. an element divisible by $ \,3.$

**Remark** $ $ The same method [works to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189787/242) that a sequence of $d$ consecutive integers contains a multiple of $d.\,$ Alternatively this can be proved by [using division with remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2395067/242) (which has a natural proof by induction), which is closely connected to the above method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative proof that *doesn't* use induction - just for fun!

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Observe that $a^3 - a = a(a^2 - 1) = (a-1)a(a+1)$ is the product of three consecutive integers, hence divisible by three. Adding $3a$ to the initial expression does not alter divisibility by $3$.

In particular, $a^3 - a + 3a = a^3 + 2a = a(a^2 + 2)$ is divisible by $3$, which means that it is still an integer after dividing by $3$. **QED**

(A ridiculous version of the above: $a(a^2+2)$ is the sum of $a^3 - a$ and $3a$, where the latter addend is a multiple of three by observation, and the former is divisible by three by Fermat's Little Theorem; so, their sum is divisible by three, and its quotient by three is an integer. **QED**)

Comment: Really like this one!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing the proof in a more linear fashion which is easier to read. Below is how I would approach the induction step.

---

Let $P(n)$ be the statement $3\mid n(n^2+2)$.

Proving $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$:

$$P(k)\implies 3\mid k(k^2+2)$$
$\implies$
$$3\mid k(k^2+2)+3(k^2+k+1)$$
$\implies$
$$3\mid k^3+3k^2+5k+3$$
$\implies$
$$3\mid(k+1)(k^2+2k+3)$$
$\implies$
$$3\mid(k+1)((k+1)^2+2)$$
$\implies$
$$P(k+1)$$

Comment: It has to do more with that I'm not yet fluent in latex. But I'll try and write it again following the way you do it

Comment: @Mr.Lu You might find insightful to learn the idea behind the above induction step. Notice
$${\rm if}\ \  3\mid f(k)\ \ {\rm  then}\ \  3\mid f(k\!+\!1) \iff  3\mid f(k\!+\!1)-f(k)$$
So to prove the inductive step we need only verify  $\,3\mid f(k\!+\!1)-f(k) = 3(k^2+k+1),\,$ which is clear. This is a special case of [telescopic induction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20telescopy%20induction)

Answer (score 0):

If a is divisible by 3, then 3 divides a, and therefore a(a^2 + 2).

Otherwise, $a = 3k ± 1$, and 3 divides $(a^2 + 2)$ = $((3k ± 1)^2 + 2)$ = $((9k^2 ± 6k + 1) + 2)$ = $(9k^2 ± 6k + 3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Any number is congruent to $0$, $1$ or $2$ modulo $3$, and upon squaring you get any square is congruent to $0$, $1$ or $1$ modulo $3$. Now take an arbitrary number $a$. If $3$ divides $a$ then you're done, if not $a^2+2$ is, by the above, congruent to $0$ modulo $3$ since $1+2=3$, and so you're good, too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, i.e. "Can I do it simpler *using induction*" (my emphasis) since there is no (explicit) induction above.

Comment: It does if you remove the last 'using induction'. OP can benefit from it, and learn how to write down proofs without filling up a whole page with symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards.  It's far more natural.

$(k+1)((k+1)^2+2)=$

$(k+1)(k^2+2k+1+2)=$

$(k+1)(k^2+2)+(k+1)(2k+1)=$

$k (k^2+2)+(k^2+2)+(k+1)(2k+1)=$

$3m+(k^2+2)+(2k^2+3k+1)=$

$3m+3k^2+3k+3$.

It is sometimes easier to subtract results.

$(k+1)((k+1)^2+2)-k (k^2+2)=$

$k (k+1)^2+(k+1)^2+2k+2-k^3-2k=$

$k^3+2k^2+k +k^2+2k+1+2-k^3=$

$3k^2+3k+3$

is a multiple of 3.

But it's probably easiest not to use induction at all.

Let $a \equiv i \mod 3;i=0,\pm 1$

If $i=0$ then $3|a $ so $3|a (a^2+2) $

Otherwise  $i=\pm 1$

So $a^2+2\equiv i^2+2\equiv 1+2\equiv 0\mod 3$

So $3|a^2+2$ so $3|a (a^2+2) $.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use mod yet.

Comment: Then don't.  Let $a = 3m +i$ where $i = 0, 1$ or $-1$.   If $i = 0$ then $a(a^2+2) = 3m(a^2 + 2)$ is divisible by $3$.  If $i = \pm 1$ then $a(a^2 + 2) = a((9m^2 \pm 6m +1)+ 2)=a(9m^2 \pm 6m + 3)$ is divisible by $3$.  Those are the only three options.