# If $k$ is odd, then $(k-1)k(k+1)$ is divisible by $24$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I show this?
I tried letting $k=2n+1$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then

$$(k-1)k(k+1) = 4n(2n + 1)(n+1).$$

I have shown that $4n(n+1)$ is divisible by $8$... but am unsure of how to get the $3$ factor there.

Comment: One of $\,k\!-\!1,\,k,\,k\!+\!1\,$ is divisible by $3.\,$ [Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2405197/242) a sequence of $d$ consecutive integers has a multiple of $d.\ $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$4n(2n+1)(n+1)=2n(2n+1)(2n+2)$$ is the product of three consecutive integers, hence exactly one of them must be divisible by $3$

Comment: If I just consider $2n(2n+1)(2n+2)$, I can conclude it's divisible by $2$ (since there's a factor of $2$ there) and $3$, since one of them is divisible by $3$. How do I get the factor of $4$ there? (I thought I can look at the coefficient on the LHS... but wouldn't I be "double counting" the factors since 2*2 = 4)?

Comment: I seem to only be able to conclude it's divisible by $12$

Comment: @Natash1, consider two cases: if $n$ itself is divisible by 2, and when it is not.

Comment: @Natash1 If you have two consecutive even numbers (like 10 and 12; or 104 and 106) then one of them must be divisible by $4$, not just $2$. So your outer two numbers are collectively divisible by $8$ (or maybe even a higher power of $2$).

Comment: @Natash1, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126766/prove-that-one-of-n-consecutive-integers-must-be-divisible-by-n   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial/12070   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop

Comment: If there are three consecutive numbers such that the first is even, one will be divisible by 2, one by 3 and one by 4, and that's it. @Natash1

Comment: @Natash1 It is much clearer to view this in terms of $k,\,$ viz. one of $\,k\!-\!1,\,k,\,k\!+\!1\,$ must be divisible by $3.\ $

Answer (score 1):

An alternative.

Mod $3$, $k^3\equiv k$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

It's a useful fact that $1^2\equiv3^2\equiv5^2\equiv7^2\equiv1$ mod $8$. In other words, if $k$ is odd, then $k^2\equiv1$ mod $8$. So mod $8$, $k^3\equiv k$.

Together this gives that $k^3\equiv k$ mod $24$ when $k$ is odd. So $24$ divides $k^3-k=k(k-1)(k+1)$ when $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for $k=1$ because the product is zero.

Assume it is true for $k=2r-1$, then $$(2r+2)(2r+1)2r-2r(2r-1)(2r-2)=2r(4r^2+6r+2-4r^2+6r-2)=24r$$ so it is true also for $2r+1=2(r+1)-1$ and you are done by induction.

Easier, perhaps, to observe that of three consecutive integers one will be divisible by $3$ and of two consecutive even numbers one will be divisible by $4$.