# if $n>4$ is a composite number, then $(n-1)!$ is a multiple of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that if $n>4$ is a composite number, then $(n-1)!$ is a multiple of $n$?

I don't have an idea, where to start. Grateful for a hint.

Comment: This is probably also an $n$th duplicate with $n > 4$.

Comment: This is [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem).

Comment: Is it, @Lucian? WT is for primes, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$\;n>4\;$ composite $\;\implies \,\exists\,1<a,b\le n-1\;\;s.t.\;\;ab=n\;$.

Now write carefully the expression for $\;(n-1)!\;\ldots$

Comment: The obvious obstacle here is if $a=b$. You may want to add a further hint indicating how this issue is solved (this may clarify to the OP why the restriction to $n>4$ plays a role beyond the fact that "if $n=4$ then the result fails").

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, shall we let the OP reach his own conclussions and problems and, in case of need, he can write back...My point was the OP could arribe **by himself** to the interrogation "hey, why the $\;n>4\;$ condition??", and now you blew it...

Comment: No, my impression with questions at this level is that these issues are too subtle to be detected if the question needs to be asked in the first place.

Comment: This question seems to be at level of  senior high school or even college/university: not that low to demmand from peopl t check carefully what they write.

Comment: I agree with Andres, this answer has a **major gap,** and it is pedagogically misleading to give no hint of that.

Comment: @DonAntonio could please tell why n=4 doesn't work like how can we prove rigorously ,in writing it's obvious

Comment: @RiyaVerma Simply because  $\;4\nmid 3!=6\;$ ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\:\!\ n\, =\, \color{#C00}a\:\!\color{#0A0}b\mid1\!\cdot\! 2\cdots\color{#C00} a\:\color{#0A0}{(a\!+\!1)\, (a\!+\!2) \cdots (a\!+\!b)}\cdots (\color{#0af}{ab\!-\!1})=(n\!-\!1)!\ $ when $\rm\, \color{#0a0}{a\!+\!b} \le \color{#0af}{ab\!-\!1} $

$\rm\color{#0A0}b\,$ divides $\rm\color{#0A0}{green}$ product [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126788/242)  a sequence of $\rm\,b\,$ consecutive integers has a multiple of $\rm\,b,\,$ and

$\rm\, \color{#0af}{ab\!-\!1} \ge \color{#0a0}{a\!+\!b},\:$ i.e. $\rm\, (\underbrace{a\!-\!1}_{\large \ge\,1})(\underbrace{\color{#c0d}{b\!-\!1}}_{\large\ge\, 2}) \ge 2\,$ is true: $\rm\,a,b\ge 2,\,$ but $\rm\underbrace{not\ both =2,}_{\large n\,=\,ab\,\ne\, 4}\,$ so $\,\color{#c0f}{\rm one}$ is $\,\ge 3.$

Comment: I didn't downvote (I even cannot...), but I don't have idea what this answers says.

Comment: @Timbuc It's a hint to show how to infer that $\rm\,n\mid (n-1)!$ when $\rm\,n = ab\,$ is composite $> 4.\,$ If you can tell me precisely where you are stuck I can explain further. Note $\ x\mid y\ $ means $x$ divides $y.\ $

Comment: Thank you sir. At the first line you mean that $\;ab\;$ divides all that product $\;1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot a(a+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(ab-1)\;$? Ah, I see...because $\;b\;$ divides the greens...right, but why do you write "when $\;a+b\le ab-1\;$, and what happens if this is not true?

Comment: @Tim The inequality $\,a+b\le ab-1\,$ implies that the $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ sequence of factors is a *subsequence* of the factorial factors, since its end term $\,a+b\,$ is no greater than the end term $\,ab-1\,$ of the factors in the product $\,(ab\!-\!1)! = (n\!-\!1)!\ $